# Batch script to remove trailing spaces in a text file for each line

Tags: batch-file

For Eg My text file say R2.txt has the below text:

```
Hai My name is Ragaaav SPACE SPACE SPACE
I am 22 yrs old SPACE SPACE SPACE SPACE

$ % ^&*() |||| SPACE SPACE
```

The below code is working fine for the above first two lines. But if I introduce the pipe symbol'|' in any of the line the space is not removing. Instead I find the repetition of the line containing the PIPE symbol.

```
@echo off > R1.txt & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (R2.txt) do (
call :sub1 %%a
>> R1.txt echo.!S!
)

goto :eof

:sub1
set S=%*
goto :eof
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.TrimRightFOR

Comment: Should I want to make any changes in the Call function? so that even If I introduce the PIPE '|' symbol, the space gets removed

Comment: Try with `call :sub1 "%%~a"`, then in the subroutine, state `set "S=%*"`;

Answer (score 2):

A little SET /P trickery should work.

Edit: sorry forgot the trim portion.
Change the 31 to a larger number if you need more than 31 spaces removed from the end.

EDIT: input changed so had to change the code to allow for empty lines.

```
@echo off > R1.txt & setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
for /f "tokens=1* delims=]" %%a in ('find /N /V "" ^<R2.txt') do (
    SET "str=%%b"
    for /l %%i in (1,1,31) do if "!str:~-1!"==" " set "str=!str:~0,-1!"
    >>R1.txt SET /P "l=!str!"<nul
    >>R1.txt echo.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem: your `call´ parameter has to be quoted, so the poison characters are save.

You have a second problem when you come back from the subroutine: removing the quotes from the string makes the poision characters poisonous again. But you can write the quoted strings without the qoutes with a little trick:

```
@echo off 
REM create empty file:
break>R1.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM prevent empty lines by adding line numbers (find /v /n "")
REM parse the file, taking the second token (*, %%b) with delimiters
REM ] (to eliminate line numbers) and space (to eliminate leading spaces)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=] " %%a in ('find /v /n "" ^<R2.txt') do (
  call :sub1 "%%b"
  REM write the string without quotes:
  REM removing the qoutes from the string would make the special chars poisonous again
  >>R1.txt echo(!s:"=!
)

REM Show the written file:
type r1.txt 
goto :eof

:sub1
set S=%*
REM do 10 times (adapt to your Needs):
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do (
  REM replace "space qoute" with "quote" (= removing the last space
  set S=!S: "="!
)
goto :eof
```

(adapt the `10` to your needs (max number of spaces to be removed))

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Your code works much fine. But I find the blank lines in the R2.txt is not appearing in the R1.txt fine.How can I come out from this?

Comment: Will you explain me your code? so that I can understand how it works

Comment: I noticed, you edited your question with an empty line in R2.txt after I posted my answer. I adapted my answer after this, it should work now.

Comment: FOR /F always skips blank lines.

Comment: @Ragaav try again please. Removes leading and trailing spaces now and does not skip empty lines.

Comment: Please anyone explain me the above BAT script

Comment: @Ragaav: done. If you have problems with a specific command, please ask again.